# Emgu CV ArucoInvoke.InterpolateCornersCharuco gives error "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()'"

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to detect charuco markers with EmguCV and I've copied and rewritten the [example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d4a/tutorial_charuco_detection.html) from the OpenCV website.

My code looks as follows:

```cs
Mat cameraMatrix = new Mat(new Size(3, 3), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 1);
Emgu.CV.Matrix<float> matrix = new Emgu.CV.Matrix<float>(3, 3);
matrix.Data[0, 0] = 925.6412f;
matrix.Data[0, 2] = 640.055f;
matrix.Data[1, 1] = 925.4835f;
matrix.Data[1, 2] = 338.2524f;
matrix.Data[2, 2] = 1;
cameraMatrix = matrix.Mat;
Mat distCoefficients = new Mat(new Size(5, 1), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 1);
Emgu.CV.Matrix<float> matrix2 = new Emgu.CV.Matrix<float>(5, 1);
matrix2.Data[0, 0] = 0;
matrix2.Data[1, 0] = 0;
matrix2.Data[2, 0] = 0;
matrix2.Data[3, 0] = 0;
matrix2.Data[4, 0] = 0;
distCoefficients = matrix2.Mat;
var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("test.png");
var imageOut = new Image<Bgr, byte>(image.Width, image.Height);
var dictionary = new Dictionary(Dictionary.PredefinedDictionaryName.Dict4X4_100);
var detectorParameters = DetectorParameters.GetDefault();
var rejected = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
var board = new CharucoBoard(5, 5, 0.04f, 0.03f, dictionary);
VectorOfInt ids = new VectorOfInt();
VectorOfVectorOfPointF corners = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
ArucoInvoke.DetectMarkers(image, dictionary, corners, ids, detectorParameters, rejected);
if (ids.Size> 0)
{
    var charucoIds = new VectorOfInt();
    var charucoCorners = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
    ArucoInvoke.InterpolateCornersCharuco(corners, ids, image, board, charucoCorners, charucoIds, cameraMatrix, distCoefficients);
    // if at least one charuco corner detected
    if (charucoIds.Size > 0)
    {
        ArucoInvoke.DrawDetectedCornersCharuco(imageOut, charucoCorners, charucoIds, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0));
        Mat rvec = new Mat();
        Mat tvec = new Mat();
        bool valid = ArucoInvoke.EstimatePoseCharucoBoard(charucoCorners, charucoIds, board, cameraMatrix, distCoefficients, rvec, tvec);       
        if (valid)
            ArucoInvoke.DrawAxis(imageOut, cameraMatrix, distCoefficients, rvec, tvec, 0.1f);
    }
}
imageOut.Save("out.png");
```

At the `ArucoInvoke.InterpolateCornersCharuco` method I get the exception:

> OpenCV: 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()"

while `corners.Size -> 12` and `ids.values -> int[11]`.

Here is my sample image:

[image: Charuco marker test image]

What am I doing wrong? I'm using EmguCV version 4.1.1.3497. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I found the solution. For some reason the output type of de detected charuco corners was not correct.

Changing

```cs
var charucoCorners = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
```

to

```cs
var charucoCorners = new Mat();
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a ".png" image from the link you gave and it didn't show any errors. However, when I tried it with this: [image: your image] which is ".jpg", it showed. Try using a ".png" image instead.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the problem. However, the image I'm using to test is actually a png, it's just the uploaded image that is jpg. Also the original image from the website is not working for me either.

Comment: Can you put this "png" image?

Comment: You can find the png [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hUNbRwCLJDOPPI4oxKvjitIPe-uPUJlt/view?usp=sharing)